# Cannot Access Command in WPF UserControl's DataGrid Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am not able to execute Command (TestCommand) in user control may be because DataGrid of usercontrol using FileDetailsList(List)

The following is the wpf form and i am using MVVM

```
<Window>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Result">
            <USERCONTROL:FileSearchResult></USERCONTROL:FileSearchResult>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

The below is the user control

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemSource="{Binding FileDetailsList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>View
                                <Button.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu FontSize="11">
                                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FileId}" Header="Splitter Errors"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Button.ContextMenu>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FileId}" Header="File ID"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FileName}" Header="File Name"/>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The below is the view model

```
public class FileDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<FileDetail> _fileDetailsList = new List<FileDetail>();

    public RelayCommand<Int32> TestCommand { get; private set; }
    public FileDetailsViewModel()
    {
         TestCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(OpenTestCommand);
    }

    private void OpenTestCommand(int fileId)
    {
         ///Some code
    }        

    public List<FileDetail> FileDetailsList { get { return _fileDetailsList; } set { _fileDetailsList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FileDetailsList"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Please help solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

you try this it will work 100%,

```
 <Button Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                                    View
                                    <!--  Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.  -->
                                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu FontSize="11">
                                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.TestCommand,
                                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding FileId}"
                                                      Header="Splitter Errors" />
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                                </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use menuitem command binding like this,

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid }}"
```

Comment: Now i moved the entire xaml to the form and tried executing but its still not working :(

Comment: it is not working, because `ContextMenu` has its own VisualTree, therefore you cannot traverse VisualTree up to the DataGrid,

Comment: May I know why? Do i need to change the context menu?

Comment: WPF creates new window foreach context menu. Each window has its own visual tree, therefore you cannot find element from another window using RelativeSource

Answer (score 0):

WPF rule number 1:

### When binding does not work, check your output window!

you would see error saying, that TestCommand does not exist in FileDetails. This is because DataContext of each row in DataGrid and all descendant elements including your ContextMenu is not `FileDetailsViewModel` but `FileDetail`

**easiest workaround is to move TestCommand to FileDetail class.**

alternativelly, you can modify the binding to point to FileDetailsViewModel. Give name to root element in your UserControl or Window, e.g: LayoutRoot. Then use ElementName in the binding:

```
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding LayoutRoot.DataContext.TestCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding FileId}" 
              Initialized="ContextMenu_Initialized"/>
```

```
    private void ContextMenu_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameScope.SetNameScope((ContextMenu)sender, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
    }
```

another way how to fix the binding is workaround proposed by @jobyjames85, but it is little hacky. On the other side it is plain xaml solution with no codebehind involved

Comment: Thanks for the tip let me check